# ошибка: OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:

Tags: python, python-3.x

Выдает в консоле такую ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\python\ass.py", line 48, in <module>
file1 = open(file_name_one, 'r')
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'Write here witch file do you want to copy?: '
```

вот код:

```
file_name_one = ('Write here witch file do you want to BACKUP?: ')
file_name_two = 'backup_' + file_name_one

file1 = open(file_name_one, 'r')
file2 = open(file_name_two, 'w')

file2.write(file1.read())

file1.close
file2.close

print("BACKUP completed successfully")
```

Comment: Уважаемый автор, стоило бы добавить в вопрос задачу, решаемую Вашей программой. И ещё вопрос: код копировался из какого-то примера?

Comment: Задачей является простое копирование файла в новый файл.

Comment: Да, это из видео Хауди ХО

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Банально пропустили `input()`:

```py
file_name_one = input('Write here witch file do you want to BACKUP?: ')
file_name_two = 'backup_' + file_name_one

file1 = open(file_name_one, 'r')
file2 = open(file_name_two, 'w')

file2.write(file1.read())

file1.close()
file2.close()

print("BACKUP completed successfully")
```

Comment: Упс... спасибо)))

Comment: @NarimanMagomedov Отметьте, пожалуйста, ответ, как решение, если он был полезен. Код откуда-то скопирован?

Comment: @NarimanMagomedov Обратите внимание на скобки после  `file.close`, без них бы тоже не работало.

Comment: Хорошо. Да, я пытался повторить код из видеоуроков Хауди Хо

Comment: Насчет скобок заранее спс)

Comment: @NarimanMagomedov Не моё дело, наверное, но я не советовал бы изучать язык таким образом. В смысле пытаться воспроизвести готовое решение. С моей точки зрения (не берусь утверждать, что она правильная) лучше было бы изучить значение отдельных операторов и функций и затем написать код самому с нуля.

Comment: скорее соглашусь, чем нет. Как раз начал заниматься с книгой Марк Лутц 4-е издние. Спасибо за советы))

Comment: @NarimanMagomedov Всегда рад помочь. Книга хорошая, но в сети доступно более "свежее" 5ое издание (здесь нельзя прикреплять ссылки на такие сайты, поэтому просто сообщаю).